# Не понимаю как написать код программы

Tags: python

Только начал изучать python столкнулся с вот такой задачкой, не совсем понимаю как решить ее:
Нужно ввести с клавиатуры адрес электронной почты и отделить от него все что находиться после символа "@" (Например, для ivan@gmail.com это gmail.com)

Answer (score 5):

```
print(input('email: ').split('@')[1])
```

---

Метод `split()` разделит строку, полученную через `input()`, на список строк по символу "@".

Например, для `test@gmail.com`, вы получите список: `["test", gmail.com"]`.
Далее можно просто забрать `gmail.com` оттуда.

Но если знака "@" не окажется в строке - вы получите ошибку, из-за доступа по неверному индексу.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
example = 'My email is jobs.kh@mail.ru'
pattern = r'\b.+@(\w+)\b'
print(re.search(pattern, example).groups(1)) # ('mail.ru', )
```

Comment: регулярки тут явно лишний...

Comment: хотя как вариант норм... Но на практике не рекомендую городить regex, там где битл-инов за глаза хватит